# codeigniter - conditional if else statement using a href

Tags: codeigniter, if-statement, conditional-statements

I know this is a weird question, but let me explain more. I use codeigniter as framework to make my site. I have some code that contain `if else` condition in view and want to use that as `a href` so it becomes like a button that changes based on whether the condition has been met or not.

here is the code:

```
<?php if($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
{      echo anchor("auth/logout/","Logout");
}      else { 
       echo anchor("auth/login/","Login");
?>
```

I was looking around in the net, but couldn't find a similar case where **if else** statement being used.

any idea how to achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work fine, as long as `tank_auth` is loaded and you have a closing bracket after your `else` condition:

```
<?php 
if($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()) {
  echo anchor("auth/logout/","Logout");
} else { 
  echo anchor("auth/login/","Login");
}
?>
```

You might also consider moving your check for the user's login to your controller, however, so as to keep `tank_auth` out of your views:

```
  // ...end of controller function
  $data['logged_in'] = $this->tank_auth->is_logged_in();
  $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
}
```

In this case, you would then run your conditional on `$logged_in` in your view.

Comment: @riz. Thanks for your comment, but perhaps you didn't read the question well or you misunderstood what required. I know that the code works fine, but I want to use it in **a href** instead as a button

Comment: `anchor` (as you're using it) will create an `<a>` tag (see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html). If it's showing up as a button instead of a link, you have an issue with your CSS--not the PHP beneath it.

Comment: ok, what if I want to use that code in a table, how do I place the code inside a table?

Comment: By wrapping it in a table tag... `<table><tr><td><?php /* code here */ ?></td></tr></table>`

Comment: I guess you are right about setting the function in the controller rather than being in the view. Thanks, mate.